# convert a string to date object javascript returns an incorrect date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert string to a date object in javascript, however what i day that is minus 1 from day in string. I don't know what is wrong. Here is the method

```
function formatDate(date_str)
{
   console.log(date_str); //input : 2020-03-11

    let new_date = new Date(date_str);

    console.log(new_date); //output : Tue Mar 10 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

    return new_date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that parsing the input string "2020-03-11" with no other information equates it to a date of March 11, 2020 at midnight UTC. When you are in a different time zone, then it calculates your time zone offset and gives you a time four hours earlier which would be the day before in local time.

Comment: how to fix this ?

Comment: @Xris Without knowing your use case, I'm not sure what you mean by "fix". If you want the current time, you'd use `Date.now()`. If you want it localized, you'll need to construct the date differently. This link might help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

**Why such behavior:**

The date string(`2020-03-11`) did not specify any time zone, when you attempt to create a Date object with this string, JavaScript would assume the time zone to be UTC so the date is internally dealt with like as: `2020-03-11T00:00:00Z`.
`console.log(new_date)` would internally call `.toString()` method on the `new_date` object and doing that would trigger a date conversion to your local time zone. From the question I believe you(the time on your machine actually) are in `GMT-4`, this is why 4 hrs is being subtracted from the output of the logs. More details about the date conversion due to time zone [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**Possible Fix:**
Firstly, we should understand that this is not a bug or an error, it is just how the JavaScript Date object works.
For the scenario described in your question, I'm guessing what you want is to avoid this time zone conversion on the date string. What you can do is add timezone information to the date string before using it to instantiate a date object, with this, javascript wouldn't assume that the date string you are passing into the Date() constructor is in UTC, and when you call Date.toString() or any other similar methods, there won't be any surprises. An implementation for this can be something like this:

```
// Sorry for the super long function name :)
function add_local_time_zone_to_date_string (date_string) {
    // Getting your local time zone
    let local_time_zone = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * -1) / 60;
    // local_time_zone is a number, convert it to a string
    local_time_zone = (local_time_zone.toString())
    // Padding with 0s if needed to ensure it is of length 2
    local_time_zone = local_time_zone.padStart(2, '0');
    return `${date_string}T00:00:00+${local_time_zone}`
}

function formatDate(date_str) {
    console.log(date_str); //input : 2020-03-11

    const date_with_time_zone = add_local_time_zone_to_date_string(date_str);
    let new_date = new Date(date_with_time_zone);

    console.log(new_date); //output : There should be no surprises here

    return new_date;
}
```